# Show element when the user starts typing

Tags: javascript

Is this possible with javascript? Right now, I use this, which shows the element when the TextArea is focused. But could I make it show only if it's focused and something has been entered in the TextArea?

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <textarea onfocus="document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';" id="text" style="width: 540px; height: 50px; overflow:hidden;"></textarea>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:hidden">
</form>
```

#### Edit

Tried SpenserJ's code but It just wont work. The submit button wont show up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#text {
 width: 540px;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#submit {
display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
var textInput = document.getElementById('text')
, submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
function checkTextValue() {
if (textInput.value !== '') {
submitButton.style.display = 'block';
} else {
submitButton.style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post">
<textarea onkeypress="checkTextValue()" onkeyup="checkTextValue()" onchange="checkTextValue()" id="text"></textarea>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: NAA but `display:hidden` should be `display:none`

Comment: Use the `keydown` or `keyup` event, and check the textarea's `value` property to see if it contains anything

Answer (score 1):

Use onkeypress, onkeyup, and onchange to detect changes in the value, and then set the display according to whether it is empty.

http://codepen.io/SpenserJ/pen/xKmcs

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <textarea onkeypress="checkTextValue()" onkeyup="checkTextValue()" onchange="checkTextValue()" id="text"></textarea>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
var textInput = document.getElementById('text')
  , submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
function checkTextValue() {
  if (textInput.value !== '') {
    submitButton.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    submitButton.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
#text {
  width: 540px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#submit {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: In your edit, you have the `<script>` in the `<head>`, which will be parsed before the DOM is loaded. If you try typing with the console open, you'll see the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`. This is because we set the textInput and submitButton variables before the elements existed. The solution is to **move the `<script>` to just before the `</body>`**, where it will execute _after_ the elements are created.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for my rush response before, here is a correct version of it and it uses `onblure` instead of `onfocus`, you can also use `keyup,keydown,keypress`..

```
function checkFortextAreaValue(textArea){
    if(textArea.value.length > 0){
        document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        alert('textArea is empty');
    }
}

<form action="#" method="post">
    <textarea id="text" style="width: 540px; height: 50px; overflow:hidden;" onblur="checkFortextAreaValue(this); "></textarea>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:hidden" />
</form>
```